# Ubuntu Space Allocation on Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

Warm Wishes
I'm a student of Electronics background and I'm very much interested in python and JavaScript
I'm planning to shift to Ubuntu (20.04LTS) from Windows 10
My SSD has 101GB Free space.

How much space should I allocate to Ubuntu for Machine leaning and other programming stuff?

Laptop : Lenovo Legion Y540
RAM    : 8GB
SSD    : 256 GB

Much Thanks

Vraj Parikh :)